# Pandas sql python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to find same salary in emp table using pandas dataframe
Below dictionary name employee so create as a dataframe
And find same salary in employee dataframe

employee={'Name':['Bob','Steve','Mark','Lisa','Hans'],'Station':[ 1,2,3,4,5],'Salary':[2000,1750,2050,2200,2000]} employee

Comment: please clarify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby on `Salary` column then filter out the group which has no same salary.

```py
df.groupby('Salary').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```